# Why is my text turning into A's in Blender?

Tags: edit-mode

I have an Emperor's New Groove custom font, and I wanted to use it in Blender. But when I type something in it, the characters are all A's.

[image: this is the text that it turned into. The text I typed is "ohno".]

Comment: Does the font work ok in other applications?

Comment: Well, it does, but in Blender, the font starts to act really unforgiving and tease-ish when it comes to those Inca cases.

Comment: What class of font is it?

Comment: TTF. Most TrueTypes would act forgiving during use in the software but not this!